# How do I use one Material Dialog multiple times but subscribe to a different auth method depending on the button that was clicked?

Tags: angular, typescript, express, angular-material, nodemailer

I'm building an authentication app using the PEAN stack (i.e., PostgreSQL - ExpressJS - Angular - NodeJS).

I have two JavaScript files on the backend using ExpressJS (i.e., `edit-profile-email.js` and `edit-profile-username.js`) and one Angular component on the frontend (i.e., `edit-profile.component.ts`).

The flow is the following:

1. The user enters a new email/username
2. The user needs to enter the password in the Material Dialog
3. If the password is correct, the user gets a verification email
4. The user clicks on the button and verifies profile changes

I was having a problem with the Nodemailer where the user could only change the email and received a verification email, whereas changing the username gave the `No recipients defined` error.

I understand this error, but the error persisted even if I hardcoded the email as follows:

```
const options = {
  from: process.env.ETHEREAL_EMAIL,
  to: 'test@test.com', // Hardcoded
  subject: 'My app — Confirm your username profile change',
  template: 'edit-profile',
  context: {
    user: getEmail,
    link: editProfileLink,
  },
};
```

I figured out that the `No recipients defined` error might be caused because I used the same API endpoint in both files as follows, but the code was a bit different (i.e., in case the user changed email, the confirmation email was sent to the *new* email, whereas in case the user changed username, the confirmation email was sent to the current email):

**edit-profile-email.js** (backend)

```
/* ... */

// STEP 2: The user enters the password
router.post('/api/edit-profile-password-confirmation', async (req, res) => { ... });

/* ... */
```

**edit-profile-username.js** (backend)

```
/* ... */

// STEP 2: The user enters the password
router.post('/api/edit-profile-password-confirmation', async (req, res) => { ... });

/* ... */
```

I decided to create two auth methods with different API endpoints instead of using one auth method with the same API endpoint:

BEFORE:

**auth.service.ts** (frontend)

```
editProfilePasswordConfirmation(confirmationPassword?: string) {
  return this.http.post(
    this.authUrl + 'api/edit-profile-password-confirmation',
    { password: confirmationPassword },
    { withCredentials: true }
  );
}
```

NOW:

**auth.service.ts** (frontend)

```
editProfilePasswordConfirmationEmail(confirmationPassword?: string) {
  return this.http.post(
    this.authUrl + 'api/edit-profile-password-confirmation-email',
    { password: confirmationPassword },
    { withCredentials: true }
  );
}

editProfilePasswordConfirmationUsername(confirmationPassword?: string) {
  return this.http.post(
    this.authUrl + 'api/edit-profile-password-confirmation-username',
    { password: confirmationPassword },
    { withCredentials: true }
  );
}
```

#### Problem

**The problem now is that I want to use one Material Dialog where the user enters a password, but I want to subscribe to a different auth method depending on the button that was clicked.**

- If the user clicks the *Save changes* button to change the email, the Material Dialog should open, and when the user enters the password, the Material Dialog component should subscribe to the `editProfilePasswordConfirmationEmail` auth method.
- If the user clicks the *Save changes* button to change the username, the Material Dialog should open, and when the user enters the password, the Material Dialog component should subscribe to the `editProfilePasswordConfirmationUsername` auth method.

#### Question

**How do I use one Material Dialog multiple times but subscribe to a different auth method depending on the button that was clicked?** If I need to have two Material Dialog components, what's the point of using a component-based framework if I can't reuse components?

Comment: I would recommend creating a method in your service that when you call it, that method displays the dialog. Assign the dialog to a const and listen for on/after closed and it should return something that indicates which auth method to use.

Comment: @MylesMorrone Thanks for the response. I managed to solve the problem as follows: 1) Set the tab index to `localStorage` on tab click (buttons are inside two tabs). The default value is `0`. 2) On button click, check the tab index value from `localStorage`. If the tab index is equal to `0`, then use the `editProfilePasswordConfirmationEmail` method. If the tab index is equal to `1`, then use the `editProfilePasswordConfirmationUsername` method.